# how to reverse message on clik button vue js

Tags: vue.js

i want to reserve paragraph after click button
reserve paragraph is showing in second paragraph 
for my case is i have to use template ?
here is my code

```
<div id="example">
        <p>Original Message: "{{ message }}"</p>
        <p id="pReserve"></p>
        <button @click="reserve">Reserve</button>
    </div>    

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
    <script>
        Vue.component('coba',{

        });
       var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#example',
        data: {
            message: 'Hai'
        },
        computed: {
            // a computed getter
            reversedMessage: function () {
            // `this` mengarah ke instance vm
            return this.message .split('').reverse().join('')
            }
        },
        methods: {
            reserve:{

            }
        },
        })

    </script>
```

Comment: you never use `reversedMessage` anywhere ... and you alternate between `reserve` and `reverse` in your question and code ... the two words have different meanings :p

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    message: 'Hai'
  },
  methods: {
    reversedMessage: function() {
      this.message = this.message.split('').reverse().join('');
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <p>Original Message: "{{ message }}"</p>
  <p id="pReserve"></p>
  <button @click="reversedMessage">Reserve</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
```